# Android - Is i possible to create custom IME that wrap other IME?

Tags: android, input, keyboard, ime

I thought about implementing kind of a soft keyboard for Android that wrap other soft keyboard to extend their functionality.

For example:

Add view above Google Keyboard ([screenshot](http://s27.postimg.org/dx51nm23n/Screen_Shot_2014_08_08_at_12_13_37_AM.png)) so that I can add emoji button, copy & paste button etc. and still use functionality from Google Keyboard such as Gesture Typing.

So:

- Is there any API to implement this kind of keyboard
- If there is no API available can it possibly be done on rooted devices

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is create an IME in Android http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html

there's an example that come with ADT that you can use to start in the folder
~\~\~\sdk\sources\android-XX\android

Comment: Thats mean I have to implement my new keyboard not wrapping the existing, right ?

Comment: myswlf I did a new one, but maybe you can add some feature to the google keyboard, i'm sure it's somewhere on the web if you search for an open source project

Comment: Is this answer your question?